# Install on Software RAID (19.10)

Tags: boot, grub2, raid

has anyone ever managed to install a ubuntu on a software RAID just using the provided install CDs?  I am trying to do what is probably a very common software need:

- two identical SSDs (each 512GB, though one weirdly now has a few less sectors)
- a root partition
- a home partition

(I presume I should have a separate /boot partition, the same way simple configs have one.)

I have been tearing my hair out.

- 19.10: the ubuntu 19.10 live-server was sort of capable creating the RAID device, but not capable of allowing me to then define partitions on /dev/md.   I then booted a gparted live USB, and finished it, so I had an 8GB /boot, a 32GB /root, and the rest /home.  I then rebooted on the ubuntu 19.10, but now it no longer recognizes that it has an installation medium.  (uhmm...it had created /dev/md itself first!)  some posts suggested that the live-server and server were different, but 19.10 only has a live-server.  [I may have mistakenly set up /boot (probably 1M and FAT are correct), but why would the installer forget its desired partitions if I want RAID??), and not even allow me to make any changes to md partitions?]
- 18.04: no problem, me thinks.  go back to 18.04 server (not live-server), install, then do-release-upgrade to 19.10.  painful, but doable.  ok, done this all...until it fails at installing grub.  no problem, I can use grub-install and hand-tell it my places, right?  well, no.  there is something called grub-installer on the 18.04 usb, but it is a different program, and lacks documentation afaik.  no man page.

given how simple my needs are---two similar identical drives, RAID-1, bootable please---this task has seemed remarkably difficult to accomplish.

---

I have given up for now, and just installed a normal non-RAID 19.10 server on one of the drives.  worked like a charm, except only one SSD.

- now I need a guide to madm-raiding sda to sdb.  In particular, I need mdadm to work for my (necessarily mounted) root partition, and I would love it if grub2 could still boot afterwards when sda becomes md0.  help, please!

---

what is the recommended low-pain way to install a ubuntu system with the security of RAID-1?

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with md raid installation from 19.10 "live-server" iso.

It is better to use:

- http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/releases/19.10/release/ubuntu-19.10-server-amd64.iso

(That's the [alternative server installer](https://ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads#alternate-ubuntu-server-installer) for 19.10.)